# Allowing others to add points to QGIS Cloud after publishing (or notes)?

Tags: qgis-cloud

How can I allow others to add points in a layer published on QGIS Cloud?
I have a map of my city and was hoping myself and friends could add notes from our phones at different locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish and share your data as WFS/T. With WFS/T you and your friends  are able to edit the data. For further information please have a look at http://blog.sourcepole.ch/2014/09/02/share-and-manage-your-data-with-qgis-cloud-and-wfs-t/